# Collectors.reducing to List

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Consider this class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class User {
    String name;
    String languages;
}
```

I have a `List<User>` and I would like to reduce on languages. Input:

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new User("sam", "java"));
list.add(new User("sam", "js"));
list.add(new User("apollo", "html"));
```

Expected output:

```
[User(name=apollo, languages=html), User(name=sam, languages=java, js)]
```

I can achieve this using following code:

```
List<User> l = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         u -> u.name,
         Collectors.reducing((u1, u2) -> 
             new User(u1.name, u1.languages + ", " + u2.languages))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(user -> user.get() != null)
    .map(user -> user.get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(l);
```

But I don't want to create two stream, can this be achieved using a single stream?

Comment: Side note: `.filter(user -> user.get() != null)`: would be problematic exactly when it's supposed to help (an exception will be raised). Use `.filter(Optional::isPresent)`

Comment: @ernest_k Better: use `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` on Java 9+.

Comment: @Nikolas This question wasn't tagged [tag:java-8] and there's no reason: it's about streams and streams only. Why add the tag when it's irrelevant?

Comment: The version of Java matters as long as the content of Stream API vary across versions. If I see [tag:java-9] or [tag:java-11] instead, I'd begin using all the tools available. Moreover, I'd rather use a specific version tag over the general [tag:java].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want to create two stream, can this be achieved using a single stream?

Of course it is possible, you have two options and in both you have to use `Collect.collectingAndThen` that extracts the correct value type from a created `Map`.

You need to use the following lambda expression first:

```
BinaryOperator<User> binaryOperator = (u1, u2) -> 
    new User(u1.getName(), String.join(", ", u1.getLanguages(), u2.getLanguages()));
```

The solutions:

1. `Collectors.toMap` with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` extracting values from the `Map<String, User>`:

   ```
   List<User> l = list.stream()                                       // Stream<User>
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.toMap(                                          // Map
               User::getName,                                         // ..name as key
               user -> new User(user.getName(), user.getLanguages()), // ..value as user
               binaryOperator),                                       // ..combined
           map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));                    // extracted value
   ```
2. `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` extracting values from the `Map<String, Optional<User>>` caused by `Collectors.reducing`:

   ```
   List<User> ll = list.stream()                     // Stream<User>
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.groupingBy(                    // Map<String, Optional<User>>
               User::getName,                        // ... name as key
               Collectors.reducing(binaryOperator)), // ... reduced value
           map -> map.values().stream()              // extracted value
               .filter(Optional::isPresent)          // ... where is Optional present
               .map(Optional::get)                   // ... get it
               .collect(Collectors.toList())));      // ... create a List<User>
   ```

Note I suppose you use [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), there *might* be a different solution using [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) or higher.

Comment: `groupingBy` is the right way to go when you want to avoid the costs of repeated string concatenation. But you have to stop the idea of *reducing* `User` instances, which is wasteful anyway, just use `.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getName, Collectors.joining(", ")), /* efficient string processing */ map -> map.entrySet().stream() .map(e -> new User(e.getKey(), e.getValue())) /* only one User object per actual user */ .collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
List<User> l = new ArrayList<> (list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(u -> u.name,
                              u -> new User (u.name,u.languages),
                              (u1, u2) -> new User(u1.name, u1.languages + ", " + u2.languages)))
    .values());
```

Comment: Wow, you made it look easy :) But I am really trying to get a `List` from stream if that is possible.